# How to get the list of a folder from ftp using Listviewcontroller class from apples simpleFtpsample project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ftp

How to get the list of a folder from ftp using Listviewcontroller class from apples simpleFtpsample project .How to use it like we use object of GetController class to download the data
please suggest

Comment: See https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon for a nice FTP library.

Comment: Did you look at the website? It shows plenty of sample code for doing lots of stuff such as getting a folder listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListController class from apple site helps to do the listing of directories.Just need to customize a bit, so that we can use the object of Listcontroller class to use it in other class  as suggested by rmaddy in the above comments